# How to represent unittest.mock.call().__str__()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

One of the mocks that I'm using contains the call `call().__str__()`.

Output of `my_mock.mock_calls`

```
[call(<MagicMock name='mock()' id='140630678530704'>, indent=2, sort_keys=True),
 call().__str__(),            # <-- what I'm trying to represent
 call()]
```

How can I represent this?

Checking that `call().__str__()` is part of the `mock_calls` is causing me difficulty as that will get converted to the string `'call()'`.

```
In [16]: mock.call().__str__()
Out[16]: 'call()'
```

Comment: Can you show the related code? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, I've added the output to show what's coming out.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you are asking - please check if the answer below is helping.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve using a `tuple` like this:

```py
inst.assert_has_calls([
    ("().__str__", (), {})
])
```

It works because `call` is [unittest.mock._Call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/86eeeb425936ba67d79f32bfbd5c5f8002819438/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2430) class alias, and `_Call` is a subclass of `tuple`.

So when you write `("().__str__", (), {})` the items are:

1. name is `"().__str__"`
2. args are `()`
3. kwargs are `{}`

Which equals `call().__str__()`.  To show you some examples in the interpreter:

```py
>>> from unittest.mock import _Call
>>> print(_Call(("().__str__", (), {})))
call().__str__()
>>> print(_Call(('name', (1,), {})))
call.name(1)
>>> _Call(('Class().__str__', (), {}))
call.Class().__str__()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if the given call is in `mock_calls`.
The standard way to check if a method has been called, is to use one of the `assert_called_xxx` methods on the created instance:

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.SomeClass')
def test1(mocked):
    inst = SomeClass()  # inst == mocked.return_value
    inst.__str__.assert_not_called()

    # use this if you don't have inst
    mocked.return_value.__str__assert_not_called()

    print(inst)
    inst.__str__.assert_called_once()
    mocked.return_value.assert_called_once()
    mocked.return_value.__str__.assert_called_once()
```

Note that instead of checking `call().__str__` on `mocked`, you check `__str__` on `mocked.return_value`, which is the result of `call()`.

If for some reason you need to directly check for the string representation of that call, e.g. `call.__str__()`, you have to check the string instead:

```
assert 'call.__str__()' in [str(c) for c in inst.mock_calls]
```

Or, if you want to check it on the class:

```
assert 'call().__str__()' in [str(c) for c in mocked.mock_calls]
```

EDIT:
Removed not working version, as pointed out by @user2357112supportsMonica, fixed incorrect usage of `mocked`.

Comment: `mocked.__str__` is not a mock and does not have an `assert_called_once` method. You'll get an `AttributeError` if you try that.

Comment: The `mocked.__str__ in mocked.mock_calls` check produces a variety of hangs and incorrect results when I test it, too.

Comment: Ok, that's strange, I tested it ok - did you use `mock.patch` to patch `SomeClass`? Can you check the type of `mocked` and `mocked.__str__`? Both should be `MagicMock`.

Comment: Looks like it is a MagicMock if you use a MagicMock. However, the hangs and wrong results for the `in` check still happen with a MagicMock. For example, [the `in` check I'm linking now hangs](https://ideone.com/7ihHsT).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the difference - you directly create a `MagicMock`, while I create the mock from a real class, that always have a `__str__` method. I can reproduce your problem, but that is because the `MagicMock` is not initialized with an object.

Comment: [The hangs still happen with `patch`.](https://ideone.com/PvpFVg)

Comment: Well, you don't use the mock - you have to check that on the mock (e.g. `mock.mock_calls` instead of `x.mock_calls`.

Comment: Right you are, that part is indeed wrong - I removed it from the answer - thank you! I was obviously confused...